# XQuery ontology view with class name

Tags: xml, xquery

So I am provided a big XML document. I have to write a query which, given a class name and ontology name, will compute an ontology view which contains the ontology parts of the document which are related to that class. More precisely, I need to select the subclasses of the class, the instances and the rules related to the class. I was thinking of doing this recursively.

Any idea of how can this be done easily?

Comment: Could you provide an example document? Otherwise it is hard to give you any useful advice.

Comment: http://rasdaman.flanche.net/dbwa/Assignment5/example.omdoc

Comment: and the result if we search for ontology "example.omdoc" and class name "Camera" is http://rasdaman.flanche.net/dbwa/Assignment5/example-result.omdoc

Comment: As this seems to be homework, what did you already try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Well actually I don't really know how to start. I don`t know how to check for instance what's the name of a class in order to select it ...

Comment: "class" ? What is this? "ontology"? What is this? More precidely, you need to provide a source XML document (as small as possible) and talk in terms of nodes of this XML document.

Comment: "precidely"? What is this? An ontology however, is a well known concept in computer/information science: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can descend the class hierarchy defined in your document via a recursive function:

```
declare default element namespace "http://omdoc.org/ns";
declare namespace om = "http://www.openmath.org/OpenMath";

declare function local:class-hierarchy(
  $doc as document-node(),
  $classname as xs:string
) as node() {
  <class name='{$classname}'> {
    for $OMA in $doc//axiom/FMP/om:OMOBJ/om:OMA
    where $OMA/om:OMS[1]/@name = 'subclass'
      and $OMA/om:OMS[3]/@name = $classname
    return local:class-hierarchy($doc, $OMA/om:OMS[2]/@name)
  }</class>
};
```

The function returns nested elements representing the subclass relationships. The subclasses of `Device` for example can be computed as follows:

```
let $doc := fn:doc("http://rasdaman.flanche.net/dbwa/Assignment5/example.omdoc"),
    $class := 'Device'
return local:class-hierarchy($doc, $class)
```

Result:

```
<class xmlns="http://omdoc.org/ns" name="Device">
  <class name="Camera">
    <class name="DSLR"/>
  </class>
</class>
```

You can easily adapt this function to return the respective classes' rules and instances instead.